# How to install glui in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: installation, 13.10

Question explains almost of it. I tried running `sudo apt-get install libglui2c2`. This gives an error `Unable to locate package libglui2c2`. This problem seems to exist only in Ubuntu 13.10. It was not even installed by default. Compiling gives an error saying "Unable to locate glui.h". How can I install glui ?

OS: Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raring has the package in "universe": [Ubuntu – Details of package libglui2c2 in raring](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/raring/libglui2c2)

But releases after that do not have it any more.

So I would advice to install it from the 13.04 repository.

You can find it here:

- [i386](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/raring/i386/libglui2c2/download)
- [amd64](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/raring/amd64/libglui2c2/download)

Download the file and click it for Ubuntu Software Center to try to install it.

Comment: Why is this removed from 13.10?

Comment: My program still says `#include "GL/glui.h" : No such file or directory`

Comment: Yeah, I found out the reason. Actually I needed one more package `libglui-dev`

Comment: here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/raring/libglui-dev  and no idea why it got removed :D edit: last activity on the package seems to be 2006... so probaly cuz it has no maintainer.

Comment: This page seems to explain partially http://box2d.org/